# numpy.fromFile read from txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I have saved a **`1000*65536`** dimension **2D** array into a text file, where each float in a row is separated by **','**.

I am unable to load the array using **`numpy.fromfile`**. Here's the script which I tried :

```
data = np.fromfile("fileName", dtype=float, count=-1, sep=',')
print(data.shape) -- > (65536, )
```

However, expected shape of **`data`** should be 1000*65536 as there are 1k rows and 65k columns in each.

Any idea?

Comment: How did you do the save?  Show a small sample of the file.

Comment: Used **`np.savetxt`** to save the data. Even one row has 65k cols so don't know how to show that. 

Each line contains a row which comprises of 65k floats separated by ','. 
e.g :
1,2,3,4....\n
5,1,2,3....

Comment: `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` pair with `savetxt`, not `fromFile`

Comment: The thing is `loadtxt` is taking insane amount of time to load. 
Coming back to the original question, why can't I use fromFile given the output file is just a csv ?

Comment: Looks like `fromfile` read just the first line.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I am wondering whether its unable to figure out "\n" at the end of the first line.

Comment: It talks about a simply formatted text file, not a multiline csv one. `loadtxt` reads the file line by line (`readline`), and splits each.  The '\n' is not the specified ',' delimiter.

Comment: So it's not possible to load using fromFile? I tried with  "\n" as delimiter, but the results is wacky. It just read one value.

Comment: @hpaulj Alternate question, what's the best way to save and load large (in order of Gbs) np arrays ?